# I have created a simple animation that moves a string across the screen. What is a more pythonic way of writing this?

Tags: python, animation

In order to simulate a string moving on one line I use `os.system("clear")`. I'd like to be able to create the animation without clearing the terminal each time. Also, is there a more explicit way of changing the previous element in the list to its original element without writing `x[pos-1] = char`? I would also love to see how other people would create a simple text animation.

```
<!-- language: lang-Python -->

import os 

def animate(photo,n,start,char = " ",_time = 1):
    x = [char for i in range(n)]

    for pos in range(start, n):
        os.system("clear")    
        x[pos] = photo
        x[pos - 1] = char
        print("".join(x))
        time.sleep(_time)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    animate("~========*>~~",50,0,_time = 0.05)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using carriage return instead of `os.system("clear")` and use the repetition form of the multiplication operator to simplify things:

```
import time

def animate(photo, n, start, char=" ", _time=1):

    for pos in range(start, n):
        print(char * pos, photo, sep='', end=chr(13))
        time.sleep(_time)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    animate("~========*>~~", 50, 0, _time=0.05)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
from time import sleep

def animate(text, repeat, pause=0.05):
  for index in range(1, repeat):
    print("\r" * (index - 1) + " " * index + text, end="")
    sleep(pause)

  print("\n")
    
animate("~========*>~~", 50)
```